# My async TcpListener getting my CPU 50-60% load sometimes

Tags: c#, async-await, tcplistener

I am stuck with this serious problem.

I have async TcpListener. Sometimes there are several connected clients and everything is fine. Sometimes even if there is one person. The server starts usage 50-60% of my CPU.

I think the problem could be in handling of reading exceptions but it's my only tip and I don't know how to test it.

Here is code for server:

```
class Server
{
    private TcpListener server;

    public Server(string hostname, int port = 25000)
    {
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(hostname), port);
    }

    public void ServerStart()
    {
        server.Start();
        WaitForClientConnect();
    }

    private async void WaitForClientConnect()
    {
        TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("The async connection created for: " + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());

        OnClientConnect(client);
    }

    private void OnClientConnect(TcpClient client)
    {
        ClientLowAPI clientReq = new ClientLowAPI(client);

        WaitForClientConnect();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for handling a single client:

```
class ClientLowAPI
{
    private TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream stream;

    public ClientLowAPI(TcpClient clientConnected)
    {
        client = clientConnected;
        stream = client.GetStream();
        WaitForHeader();
    }

    private async void WaitForHeader()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

        int bytesRead = 0;
        while (bytesRead < 4)
        {
            try
            {
                bytesRead += await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length - bytesRead);
            }
            catch
            {
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                return;
            }
        }

        WaitForData(FourBytesToInt(buffer));
    }

    private async void WaitForData(int length)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

        int bytesRead = 0;
        while (bytesRead < length)
        {
            try
            {
                bytesRead += await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length - bytesRead);
            }
            catch
            {
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                return;
            }
        }

        ExecuteMessage(buffer);
    }

    private void ExecuteMessage(byte[] binaryData)
    {
        // Do something with message
        WaitForHeader();
    }

    public async void SendMessage(byte[] message)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[message.Length + 4];
        byte[] length = IntToFourBytes(message.Length);

        length.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
        message.CopyTo(buffer, 4);

        try
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        catch
        {
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
    }

    private int FourBytesToInt(byte[] array)
    {
        int res = 0;
        res += array[0] * 256 * 256 * 256;
        res += array[1] * 256 * 256;
        res += array[2] * 256;
        res += array[3];
        return res;
    }

    private byte[] IntToFourBytes(int intValue)
    {
        byte[] array = new byte[4];
        array[0] = (byte)(intValue >> 24);
        array[1] = (byte)(intValue >> 16);
        array[2] = (byte)(intValue >> 8);
        array[3] = (byte)intValue;
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a profiler to determine hotspots.  Stack Overflow isn't a profiler.

Comment: *Don't* use `async void`. It's only meant for event handlers. You are firing off asynchronous commands without ever waiting for a response. Use `async Task` and *await* the result

Comment: Besides, reading only a single Int32's worth of data at a time guarantees a high CPU load. Even if the code worked correctly, you are spending most of the time iterating over the loop *and* closing/reopening the same connection. Use a large buffer and let `ReadAsync` do its job. Or use `Stream.CopyToAsync` to copy from one stream to another

Comment: @Amy before your comment i had no idea that something like profiler exist. The problem is that this issue is rarer than i think. I will have to probably start profiler for really long time and wait (days). Thanks

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks i will always check what can I do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by this loop:

```
while (bytesRead < 4)
        {
            try
            {
                bytesRead += await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length - bytesRead);
            }
            catch
            {
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                return;
            }
        }
```

Normally was connection killed by force and server has raised exception but sometimes the connection was properly closed by client by TcpClient.Close() then the exception was not raised and the stream.ReadAsync method start returns 0 which caused infinty loop with huge CPU usage.

for fast fix i used the following condition:

```
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            throw new System.IO.IOException();
        }
```